# $P(a \le Z \le b) = P(Z \le b) - P(Z \le a)$: How did we get $- P(Z \le a)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

My textbook claims the following:

> If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $P(a \le Z \le b) = P(Z \le b) - P(Z \le a)$.

In the above, $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ means that the random variable $X$ has a normal distribution.

I don't understand how this is true. Specifically, I don't understand where the $- P(Z \le a)$ came from.

I would greatly appreciate if people could please show me how this is true.

Comment: If you are familiar with areas under curves, this shouldn't be much of a surprise, as probability is exactly that

Comment: @Alex Oh wow, you're right. All we need to do is think about it in terms of the probability density function for a normal distribution. This comment is gold. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that's the case because it is a continuous rv. For discrete rvs the situation is similar, but different

Comment: @Alex Yes, I understand. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? I think it must be $P(a\le Z\le b)=P(Z\le b)-P(Z\le a)$

Comment: @FarrukhAtaev You're correct: I made an error. I will fix it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just that: $\qquad\mathsf P(a\leqslant Z\leqslant b) ~{=~\mathsf P\big(Z\in[a; b]\big)\\=~ \mathsf P\big(Z\in(-\infty; b] \setminus(-\infty;a)\big) \\=~ \mathsf P(Z\leqslant b)-\mathsf P(Z<a)}$

Or, if you prefer, because of the probabilities for the union of disjoint events are additive.$$\mathsf P\big(Z\in(-\infty;b]\big)~{=~\mathsf P\big(Z\in(-\infty;a)\cup [a;b]\big)\\ =~ \mathsf P\big(Z\in(-\infty;a)\big)+\mathsf P\big(Z\in[a;b]\big)}\\ \mathsf P(Z\leqslant b)~=~\mathsf P(Z<a)+\mathsf P(a\leqslant Z\leqslant b)$$

Note: This is generally true for any real valued random variable; $Z$ does not *have* to be standard normal for this result.   The distinction between $\leqslant$ and $\lt$ becomes significant when dealing with a discrete random variable.